# Uniform Convergence and Integration on $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> - Let $Q$ be rectangle in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and suppose $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of functions that are integrable on $Q$. Assume that the sequence converges to a function $f$ uniformly on $Q$. Prove that $f$ is integrable on $Q$ and that
>
> $$\int_Q f=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Q f_n$$
>
> **Note**: Use the definition of integral directly.

**My attempt.** Since $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, given $\varepsilon>0$ there is an

$N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ and all $x\in Q$ one has $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$

**So I could do nothing, may you add an answer, please? Thanks...**

Comment: @EricTowers Ahh yess.Edited

Comment: @JuliánVillaquirá Riemann

Comment: You need to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ you can find a partition such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \epsilon$.

Comment: @copper.hat I know that I need this, I couldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must show that $f$ is integrable:

Choose $\epsilon>0$ and pick $N$ such that for $n \ge N$ we have $|f(x)-f_n(x)| < \epsilon$.

Choose a partition such that $U(f_N,P) -L(f_N,P) < \epsilon$.

Note that $U(f,P)< U(f_N,P) + \epsilon \operatorname{vol}(Q) $ and similarly
$L(f,P)> L(f_N,P) - \epsilon \operatorname{vol}(Q) $.

Hence $U(f,P)-L(f,P) < U(f_N,P)-L(f_N,P)+2 \epsilon \operatorname{vol}(Q) < \epsilon+2\epsilon \operatorname{vol}(Q)$.

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary we are finished.

Comment: Thank you verryyyy much!

Comment: @JamesEnsor: You are welcome. You still need to show the integrals converge.The above needs a small amount of extra work to finish.

Comment: How did you think this: ''Note that $U(f, P)<U\left(f_{N}, P\right)+\epsilon \operatorname{vol}(Q)$ and similarly $L(f, P)>L\left(f_{N}, P\right)-\epsilon \operatorname{vol}(Q)$''? I think, it is a trick, I wouln't do this trick.

Comment: @JamesEnsor: Well, I have seen it hundreds of times. Also, if you write out the expression for say $U(f,P)$ then it is not a huge leap to see how it relates to $U(f_N,P)$. Everything is obvious afterwards :-).

Comment: Thanks :).......

Comment: How can I choose a partition?

Comment: @JamesEnsor: I don't understand what you mean? One characterisation of the Riemann integral is the (equivalent) Darboux integral (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral#Darboux_integrals), so a function $f$ is Riemann integrable **iff** for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \epsilon$. Since the $f_n$ are integrable, we can find a partition such that this holds.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose not.  Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_Q|f_n - f| > 0$.  Let $\delta = \int_Q |f_n - f| > 0$.

Hint: For any partition of $Q$ into $M$ regions, the Riemann sum for $|f_n-f|$ for $n > N$ (your $N$) is bounded by $M\varepsilon$.  In particular, for a suitably small choice of $\varepsilon$, $M\varepsilon < \delta/2$.